# UIWebView Desktop Website Won't Work

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiwebview

Partly as an exercise for learning a little iOS programming, and partly because I wish I had a WhatsApp client on iPad, I am trying to create an app that I can personally use as a WhatsApp client for my iPad. All it does is load up the web.whatsapp.com desktop site in a UIWebView like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17"])
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.webView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://web.whatsapp.com")
    let requestObj = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    //webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

This works okay. It does in fact load the correct webapp, rather than redirecting to the whatsapp home page as would usually happen when the server detects a mobile device. However, rather than presenting me with the QR Code screen for log in, it presents me with this:

[image]

Now, if I use WhatsApp Web from Safari on my iPad (and requesting Desktop version), it works perfectly fine. As you can see, I am requesting the Desktop site for my UIWebView by setting the UserAgent. Now, I am wondering why it would not work in the UIWebView, and whether perhaps there is some other header or value that needs to be set in order to convince the App to work within my UIWebView control?

**EDIT**

I have changed to WKWebView by converting Boris Verebsky's code from Objective-C to Swift. However, whilst at first I was seeing the same screen as before (telling me to use another browser), after changing it around and trying to get it to work I find myself with a blank white screen. Nothing is showing up anymore.

[image: Blank screen]

This is my full code as it currently stands:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17"
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/601.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1 Safari/601.5.17"])
        }
        self.view!.addSubview(self.webView)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://web.whatsapp.com")!
        let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: WKNavigationActionPolicy -> Void) {
        decisionHandler(.Allow)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

It may be that my conversion from Objective-C to Swift is incorrect. I am unfamiliar with Objective-C, so that is quite likely.

Comment: Your code is correct. Reason why you have blank view is transport security. Either use `https://web.whatsapp.com` as URL (note HTTPS instead of HTTP), or add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: YES` in your application info.plist.

Comment: @BorisVerebsky Thanks, it now works. Just a few other problems to overcome before I can call it finished!

Comment: which permission required for http://web.whatsapp.com page load

Comment: me try but not load http://web.whatsapp.com page please any one know  help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After checking user agent, https://web.whatsapp.com checks that client supports indexeddb, probably by some JavaScript. It's easy to notice - if you will trace all redirects your app performed, then you will find redirect to https://web.whatsapp.com/browsers.html?missing=indexeddb. In my case, I've used simple `NSURLProtocol` subclass to log all redirects. Sadly, `NSURLProtocol` no longer works with `WKWebView`.

`UIWebView` doesn't implement indexeddb at all. As far as I know, there is no easy way to implement indexeddb support myself.

You can easily check indexeddb support by accessing html5test.com in `UIWebView`. You will see something like:

[image: html5test.com result for UIWebView]

But `WKWebView` does support indexeddb:

[image: html5test.com result for WKWebView]

I've checked web.whatsapp.com loading in iOS `WKWebView` with custom user agent, taken from my desktop Safari using http://whatsmyuseragent.com, and it shows QR code as you expected. Moreover, migration to `WKWebView` will add some bonuses like improved performance and stability.

I've used following code for my test:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface ViewController () <WKNavigationDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.webView.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17";
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.whatsapp.com"];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(nonnull WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}

@end
```

Although it's Objective-C, it should be pretty straightforward to convert into swift.

**UPD:**

Reason why you have blank view with `WKWebView` is transport security. Either use `https://web.whatsapp.com` as URL (note HTTPS instead of HTTP), or add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads: YES` in your application info.plist

Comment: I have edited my question. I am not sure my conversion to swift was correct. I am not familiar with Objective C. Could you please take a look? I am now seeing a blank white screen.

Comment: @Boris that's a great explanation.. Am doing the same in android, Do you have any idea about this

Comment: In android i tried with custom user agent, at first time the webView loads QR code Page second time onwards it loads the WhatsApp.com page

Comment: Last few weeks i tried a lot but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 4):

You should really switch to use `WKWebView` and then you can simply use [`customUserAgent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKWebView/customUserAgent) to directly set your desired agent string on the web view.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot!

Comment: you mean the agent isn't set (verified with a tool like charles proxy) or the website still isn't doing what you want ?

Comment: I mean, I have already set agent, but still it don't work. Now, even web page is not loading.

Comment: Did you check what agent is actually sent in the request using a proxy tool? You'll need to show the code you've used if you see nothing at all. Include details from which delegate methods are called

Comment: You I already checked with proxy tool. can it be so because I am creating a mac app. Do you have working Demo.if yes, Can you share the same with me. my ID is raviparmar213@gmail.com

Comment: i haven't used it on OS X, i only do iOS work really, and I haven't had cause to change the agent. you did say this was for iPad though... I haven't read of any issues with setting `customUserAgent`